# How to reuse a group and/or path in android vector drawable

Tags: android, xml, vector-graphics, android-vectordrawable

I have the following vector drawable code

```
        <vector
            android:name="vector"
            android:width="9dp"
            android:height="16dp"
            android:viewportWidth="9"
            android:viewportHeight="16">

            <path
                android:fillColor="#11141C"
                android:pathData="M0,0 H9 V16 H0 Z" />

            <group
                android:name="group"
                android:pivotX="4.5"
                android:pivotY="9">
                <path
                    android:fillColor="#F57C00"
                    android:pathData="M4.5,6 c0.1,-1 0.2,-2 0.2,-3 c0,-1 -0.4,-1 -0.4,0 c0,1 0.1,2 0.2,3 z" />

                <path
                    android:fillType="evenOdd"
                    android:pathData="M4.5,6.5 c0.1,-1 0.2,-2 0.3,-3.5 c0,-1.2 -0.6,-1.2 -0.6,0 c0.1,1.5 0.2,2.5 0.3,3.5 z">
                    <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
                        <gradient
                            android:centerX="4.5"
                            android:centerY="2.5"
                            android:gradientRadius="5"
                            android:type="radial">
                            <item
                                android:color="#B9F57C00"
                                android:offset="0.0" />
                            <item
                                android:color="#00000000"
                                android:offset="1.0" />
                        </gradient>
                    </aapt:attr>
                </path>
            </group>
        </vector>
```

I want to reuse the group `"group"` with different rotations and transitions without having to write all the inner code.

In ***SVG*** there is the tag `<use>` which can be used for this job but I can't find an equivalent in android syntax